How many states does a 2-symbol turing machine need on average to compute a N bit number?
The busy beaver problem asks what is the largest number computable by a 2-symbol N-state Turing machine, however, most numbers however are not re-presentable by a smaller program.
For a sufficiently large number without any obvious patterns, we know the Turing machine to compute it must grow logarithmically to some factor. We know this since we can encode a Turing machine proportional to the size of it's number of states and the best encoding of a random number is logarithmic.
In mathematical terms, I mean
$$f = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{T(n)}{\log(n)}$$
Where $T$ is the smallest number of states of a 2-symbol Turing machine that takes exactly $n$ steps to halt.
I wonder then what the scaling factor $f$ is. Does it have a name? Is it computable? Is it's value known?
Will this even converge with $\lim$ instead of $\limsup$?

@D.W. The base of the logarithm doesn't matter, it will just change by a constant factor.

How do you measure the size of a Turing machine?  The number of states, or something else?

@D.W. Yes, the number of states

Kolmogorov complexity seems to be what you're looking for, modulo minor technical details in the phrasing of your question.
Note that each state in a Turing machine does not contain a constant amount of information: each state contains 2 transitions each instructing the tape head to write one or zero, to move left or right, and either a new state (chosen among n) or HALT. Thus, there are (4(n+1))^(2n) Turing machines with n states, which thus have a description length O(n log(n)), i.e., every state contains O(log(n)) bits of information.
